# PHP Includes - Don't run next till first finished

Tags: php

I have a page which has three includes.

```
include 'ukt/extractor/ukt_email_extract.php';
include 'ukt/extractor/cron_bet_detail.php';
include 'ukt/extractor/cron_daily_statement.php';
```

However the second two are running before the first has fully finished and that's bad news because they rely on the first one to have completed it's tasks.

Can I do anything about this?

Simon

Comment: you should post the content of each file for us to see why ..

Comment: There is no way your 2nd and 3th files to be included before the 1st file is completed. 
PHP proccess line to line (file to file) .. There is no way to skip any line in your 1st file before going to your 2nd file..
Its the same as you reading a book .. to go to next page first you must complete the current..

Comment: The first one extracts email attachments from an account. I guess this takes several seconds to several minutes to complete.
The next two use those extracted attachments to populate a DB.

Are you saying includes 2 and 3 CANNOT run until the first has to be complete and all files extracted?

Answer (score 0):

If they depend on each other maybe try something like this:

```
include 'ukt/extractor/ukt_email_extract.php';
```

Then at the end of this (ukt/extractor/ukt_email_extract.php) file(or even better after it does it's job) put:

```
include 'ukt/extractor/cron_bet_detail.php';
```

Then at the end of this (ukt/extractor/cron_bet_detail.php) file(or even better after it does it's job) put:

```
include 'ukt/extractor/cron_daily_statement.php';
```

Comment: ok - so rather than put them all in my control page I should put them at the foot of the page so that they run in order.

Comment: It all depends on what is in those files. If they're objective, then you should put the includes where the objects are fully initialized - eg. when the first file finishes it tasks then you can include the second file etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
include 'ukt/extractor/ukt_email_extract.php';
include 'ukt/extractor/cron_bet_detail.php';
include 'ukt/extractor/cron_daily_statement.php';`
```

Php executes the files in order...
It won't go to the next, untill the previous one has been finished.